# Hide a python install from Cmake's FindPython?

Tags: python, cmake

I have a Cmake project that will have a PyBind11 subproject. I am trying to write the Cmake for that subproject.

The problem is the following command:

```
find_package(Python3 COMPONENTS Interpreter Development REQUIRED)
```

This command fails because FindPython correctly determines that the interpreter and development are coming from different versions of Python. If I search for them individually, I find that the interpreter is found in:

```
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/python3.10.exe
```

While the development is being found in:

```
C:/Users/tyler.shellberg/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/libs/python37.lib
```

I only want to use the native Windows install of Python for this project, not the MSYS version. (However, I need both installed for various other things I do)

How can I "hide" the MSYS version of Python in this Cmake?

Note: This is a cross-platform project, and people working on it may have Python installed in a couple different locations.

Comment: Instead of "hiding" **unsuitable** installations hint CMake about **suitable** installation. E.g. you could set `Python3_ROOT_DIR` variable, as described in the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPython3.html) for `FindPython3` module.

Comment: Will it "fall back" to searching if this ROOT_DIR is incorrect? (As someone else may have it in a very different location) That's why I avoided that approach at first. I guess I didn't know what was meant by a "hint".

Comment: "Will it "fall back" to searching if this ROOT_DIR is incorrect?" - Yes, it will. It is responsibility of the person, who have a mess of python-related packages on their machine, to provide a correct value of the variable, which describes their environment.

Comment: @Tsyvarev This does not seem to work for me. I've set Python3_ROOT_DIR to my Windows install's location for Python (C:/Users/tyler.shellberg/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37) but it still skips right past it. Just in case I tried swapping the FIND_STRATEGY, but that didn't help either.

Comment: I just gave up and deleted C:\msys64\mingw64\bin from PATH. Also, FindPython3 appears to be broken - it does not set variables like Python_FOUND. FindPython itself appears OK though.